# HTML not showing after PHP Function

Tags: php, html, function

I have a page that will not show the bottom half of my HTML after my PHP Code. The only way I could get it to show was to place a *RETURN* at the end of the *WHILE* Loop, which also ended the loop. I know it is probably something simple and just need to find out what it is. Thanks in advance for your help.

The HTML:

```
<table border='0'>
 <thead>
     <tr>
        <th scope="cols">Select</th>
        <th scope="cols">Name</th>
        <th scope="cols">Units</th>
        <th scope="cols">Amounts</th>
        <th scope="cols">Calories</th>
        <th scope="cols">Sugars</th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
    <?php 
         //Establishs the DB connection
         $sql = new Mysql();

         //Queries the Foods
         $sql->food();
      ?> <!--NOTHING SHOWS FROM HERE DOWN-->
  </tbody>    
</table>
<h2>Training Plan</h2>
<table id="dairy">
 <thead>
     <tr>
        <th scope="cols">Select</th>
        <th scope="cols">Name</th>
        <th scope="cols">Units</th>
        <th scope="cols">Amounts</th>
        <th scope="cols">Calories</th>
        <th scope="cols">Sugars</th>
     </tr>
     ...more HTML....
```

The PHP Function:

```
function food() {
   //Query's the DB
   $result = $this->conn->query("SELECT * FROM ingredient")  or die(mysql_error());

   //Display's all of the Contents in the DB
   while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc() or die(mysql_error()))
   {
       echo'<tr class="normal" id="row'.$row['id'].'" onclick="onRow(this.id);">'."\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t".'<td><input type="checkbox" value="'.$row['id'].'" id="checkbox" /></td>'."\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t";
       echo'<td>'.$row['Name'].'</td>'."\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t";
       echo'<td>'.$row['Units'].'</td>'."\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t";
       echo'<td>'.$row['Amount'].'</td>'."\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t";
       echo'<td>'.$row['Calories'].'</td>'."\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t";
       echo'<td>'.$row['Sugar'].'</td>'."\n\t\t\t\t\t\t";
       echo'</tr>'."\n\t\t\t\t\t\t";
   }
}
```

Comment: What shows up in your error log?

Comment: Also, wow, you really need to learn about [printf()](http://php.net/printf).  And apostrophes.

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated, try to use mysqli_* or PDO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc() or die(mysql_error()))
```

The problem is in this line, if `$result->fetch_assoc()` returns falsy when there are no more rows(which I suspect it does) you script will be stopped. Leave out the die part

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
```

Comment: Yep! That was it. I appreciate the inputs. I knew it would be something simple but it always seems that error finding is hard when you staring at it for a while. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

It's not showing because you have an error. Is food a member of the $sql class?

Comment: I dont know why you got a -ve for this. I was thinking the same answer you gave, even though I agree that maybe adding a bit more to the answer would help. But I do hate it when people get trigger-happy with the ratings and leave without explaining their rationale!

Comment: Hey-ho.I should learn to put things in comments.I shouldn't have posted as an answer,with a question.